# Knockout Kendo dropdownlist get text of selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, kendo-ui

My application is MVC 5.  I am using the following Knockout Kendo dropdownlist:

```
     <input data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { dataTextField: 'name',
 dataValueField: 'id', data: foodgroups, value: foodgroup }" />
         <hr />
         Selected: <strong data-bind="text: foodgroup"> </strong>

    <script>
        var ViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            this.foodgroups = ko.observableArray([
                { id: "1", name: "apple" },
                { id: "2", name: "orange" },
                { id: "3", name: "banana" }
            ]);
            var foodgroup =
            {
                name: self.name,
                id: self.id
            };
            this.foodgroup = ko.observable();
            ko.bindingHandlers.kendoDropDownList.options.optionLabel = " - Select -";
            this.foodgroup.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                alert(newValue.name);
            });
        };
        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
    </script>
```

I am trying to get the text of the selected item.  If I use alert(newValue) I get the id, when I use newValue.name or newValue.Text I get undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `KendoDropDownList()` does not support having a complex object as a data value.
Then I think the better approach is using  `ko.utils.arrayFirst()`.

For convinience I did an [Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/r8rLjwwo/)

Hope This help

Comment: Thank you Marco, this is great.  Will it be possible to set name as an observable and just bind the name only?

Comment: When I populated the dropdownlist using ajax: var data = db.FoodGroups.Select(c => new
          {
              id = c.FoodGroupID,
              name = c.FoodGroupName
          }).ToList();
Could not get the name?

Comment: I have updated the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400673/knockout-kendo-dropdownlist-ajax-observablearray-get-selected-item-name