# Knockout-Kendo dropdownlist Ajax observableArray get selected item name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-dropdown

My application is MVC 5, I use the following Knockout-kendo dropdown list:

```
 <input data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { dataTextField: 'name', dataValueField: 'id', data: foodgroups, value: foodgroup }" />

   var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
         this.foodgroups = ko.observableArray([
         { id: "1", name: "apple" },
         { id: "2", name: "orange" },
         { id: "3", name: "banana" }
         ]);
        var foodgroup =
        {
            name: self.name,
            id: self.id
        };

        this.foodgroup = ko.observable();
        ko.bindingHandlers.kendoDropDownList.options.optionLabel = " - Select -";
        this.foodgroup.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            newValue = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.foodgroups(), function (choice) {
                return choice.id === newValue;
            });

            $("#object").html(JSON.stringify(newValue));
           alert(newValue.name);
        });
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

It works great, thanks to this answer [Knockout Kendo dropdownlist get text of selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397652/knockout-kendo-dropdownlist-get-text-of-selected-item)

However when I changed the observableArray to Ajax:

```
       this.foodgroups = ko.observableArray([]),
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '/Meals/GetFoodGroups',

                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        self.foodgroups(data);
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
                    }
                });
```

Controller - get the table from ms sql server:

```
 public JsonResult GetFoodGroups()
            {
                var data = db.FoodGroups.Select(c => new
                {
                    id = c.FoodGroupID,
                    name = c.FoodGroupName
                }).ToList();

                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

[image]

I get this error when I alert the item name

```
 Unable to get property 'name' of undefined or null reference
```

What is the difference between hardcoding the array items from using Ajax.

Comment: Where you get tis error ? On Ajax `Success()` ?

Comment: When I try to get the name of the selected item. Ajax works

Comment: Can you log `self.foodgroups()` after you assign your `success()` data ?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by log, I get the dropdownlist contents, and when I select an item, I get the correct id after subscribe(function (newValue).

Comment: I mean show the data that you receive from your controller,  but you have the same comportament with Ajax and hardcode right?

Comment: Yes, I see the data in the dropdownlist using the hardcode and the Ajax; the only difference is when I try to get the selected item name. After newValue = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.foodgroups(),  returns null using Ajax.,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103533/discussion-between-hncl-and-marco-palma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'id' field has **string** datatype in hard coded array.

[image]

The 'id' field has **number** datatype in ajax array.

[image].

So, the 'id' field has different datatypes in both arrays. However in-condition you have used **===** operator so it checks **value** as well as **datatype**.

[image]

For ajax array value is same but its datatype is different so its not returning result.

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Great catch, I used return choice.Groupid === parseInt(newValue); 
Works great, thank you.

Comment: I meant id === parseInt(newValue);